# Assigning a body's data attribute value to a variable

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I am using WordPress and I am trying to get and assign the value of a data attribute to a variable using JavaScript inside functions.php in my custom child theme.

The page renders the following body:

```
<body class="(...)" data-elementor-device-mode="desktop">
```

I have the following function:

```
  var body = document.body;
  console.log(body);
  var bodyDevice = body.dataset.elementorDeviceMode;
  console.log(bodyDevice);
```

The first console.log returns the body as expected, but the second console.log still returns "undefined".

It must be a syntax issue, since the following

```
var bodyDevice = body.clientWidth;
console.log(bodyDevice);
```

will return the current width of the body element (which solves my issue); anyway, why is

```
var bodyDevice = body.dataset.elementorDeviceMode;
console.log(bodyDevice);
```

not returning "desktop" value?

Comment: Why are you putting your Javascript inside the functions.php?

Comment: I am keeping all my custom code in two single files: styles.css and functions.php, both inside my child theme, to avoid dispersion and facilitate maintenance. Also, by putting javascript inside functions.php, I can link them to specific action and hooks in wordpress. I could enqueue external js files, but since I have only a few functions, I prefer to keep them all in one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elementor inserts the data set by JavaScript on its initialization, see line 271 : https://github.com/elementor/elementor/blob/master/assets/dev/js/frontend/frontend.js

Basically your code is returning nothing because it is executed before the Elementor has inserted the data set... So, there is no `data-elementor-device-mode` at the moment your code is executed.

Try to execute your code after the page loads using like:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var bodyDevice = document.body.dataset.elementorDeviceMode;
  console.log(bodyDevice);
};
```

Comment: Thank you. That was the issue. A correct hook that ran after Elementor inserted the data-set also worked.